# Updating Nuget caused Exception Unhandled: System.TypeLoadException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I'm starting a new master xamarin page for testing purposes and updated the nuget packages for the xamarin.android.support and xamarin.forms version. Afterwards, my program gets the exception:

The LoadApplication gets the exception error:

```
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());


Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool:_freeRenderers' (0) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000275 from typeref (expected class 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e') assembly:mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e type:System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1 member:(null) occurred
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Downgrade xamarin.forms and xamarin.forms.maps to v4.1.0.778454 in all projects.

I did it and worked perfectly

Comment: Upgraded only to downgrade back. It works though. Thanks. Any other solutions available for this issue?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Maps both at version 4.2.0.778463 worked for me while the "latest stable" 4.2.0.815419 does not.

Comment: Can confirm: latest 'stable' `4.2.0.815419` did exactly the same thing for me. Downgrading to the version mentioned above (tho I'm not using maps) fixed the problem.
So much for "stable". I thought they'd sorted this kind of problem out now.

Comment: this really helped thanks. I just wonder how the visual studio version can affect this, as apparently it works in VS 2019, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064929/6923440

Answer (score 5):

The issue is [tracked on github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7602) and the issue only triggers only Visual Studio 2017 users. If you compile the app with Visual Studio 2019, the app runs fine with [Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.815419 (4.2.0 Service Release 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.2/4.2.0-sr2).

This is caused by a [Mono change](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/11511) that made it [into Xamarin.Android in VS2019](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7602#issuecomment-535398683).

> System.Collections.Generic.Queue is available in
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
> ```
>
> It's not available in
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
> ```
>
> So if any dll that relies on Queue is complied with VS2019, and run on
>   VS2017, it will throw exception can't load Queue from mscorlib.

The Xamarin.Forms team tries now to [implement Stack and Queue internally in XF code for VS 2017 Compatibility](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/8403).

Until this is merged, the last Xamarin.Forms bit are compiled with VS2017 and work so fine with VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

Splash screen causing the crash. following answer fixed my issue with latest xamarin forms(4.2.0.815419) and in VS 2019 Ent (16.3.1)

[check here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7301#issuecomment-526091449)